# Sencha touch exclude all senchas sass/css files for custom design?

Tags: sencha-touch, sass, sencha-touch-theming

I have a fast question that I hope some1 can answer me.
I am implementing custom design for a company doing a sencha-touch app for ios and android.

When I first came it was a big mess of !importants and overrides everywhere and i couldnt touch Anything without having to backtrack stuff for 10minutes before I could set a property.

Now we have a new project with supercusom design and I am seriously thinking of excluding as much as possible and maby even everything of senchas sass/css files except for maby loading-spinner or something like that.

Or do you recomand to keep at least some of the sencha widgets? Because I dont wanna mess up sencha logic either.

thanx

Comment: I don't quite understand... Where is the custom CSS code that is the mess? Did someone actually merge it in all over the ST debug css file? If you are scrapping everything anyway for the new project why not just start over again with the base ST CSS (or custom SASS build of it)?

Comment: Also, ST2.2 beta is out there, if you an wait for the final release I know there will be some significant theming changes - including a barebones stylesheet that has only the absolute necessities for the components to render in the right spots and function correctly (everything shows up as simply blank boxes with text).

Answer (score 0):

Many of the properties of Sencha components are tied to sass functions or specific css.  For instance, layouts and layout types will be translated to css at runtime.  I've found that if you are going to use the Sencha framework it is much easier to follow the paths they provide for customization like the cls properties they include(baseCls, innerCls, cls, inputCls, etc.), then to simply override all of their x-type classes or use !important.  I would recommend you keep the sencha widgets and provide your own sass/css within these cls properties.